# Get Jobtitle in Powerapps

Tags: office-365, user-profile, powerapp, powerapps-forms

I have Sharepoint list and made a canvas powerapp of it. In powerapps i automaticaly fill the e-mailadress of the user in a texttabel by using `ThisItem.Medewerker.Email`

But now i would like to also get his or her Jobtitle. However, when I use `ThisItem.Medewerker.JobTitle` it does not work. I get a notification This Formula uses a range that is currently not supported for evaluation. What am i doing wrong here.

Comment: Is `Medewerker` column of person or group type?

Comment: Yes, Medewerker is a person or group type.

Comment: You can get all details of users from Office365Users connection. check [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/connections/connection-Office365-users) documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the Job Title of user by using `Office365Users` Connection like below:

```
Office365Users.UserProfile(ThisItem.Medewerker.Email).JobTitle
```

For more information check below documentation:

[Connect to Office 365 Users connection from Power Apps](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/connections/connection-Office365-users)

Comment: Hi, that does not seem to work. It  looks like it expects dutch. There is no Office365User, but i keeps suggesting Office365-gebruikers.

Comment: There supposed to be `Office365Users` connection as given in official Microsoft documentation. I don't know why you are not able to see it (maybe the default language  set to your tenant/profile). If you are seeing `Office365-gebruikers` connection then I would suggest you to check the methods in this connection and use the one which matches with the example given in my answer.

Comment: Found it: 

'Office365-gebruikers'.MyProfile().JobTitle

Thanks

Comment: Great. Glad it worked for you. Please [Upvote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept it as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you.